# Extracting data for specific key in json

Tags: c#, json

I send an API graph query to facebook and the response is a huge JSON response.

Here is a small part of that json:

```
"id": "100005146959001",
"albums": {
    "data": [
        {
        "id": "246858672162363",
        "created_time": "2014-02—04T23:23:13+0000" 
        },
        {
            "id": "223430357838528",
            "created_time": "2013-12-08T20:23:10+0000",
            "photos": {
                "data": [
                   {
                        "id": "242389792609251",
                        "from": {
                            "name": "Shamsi Farrokhi",
                            "id": "lO0005146959001"
                        },    
                        "picture": "https://fbcdn-photos-g-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-ask
                        "source": "https://fbcdn—sphotos—g—a.akamaihd.net/hphotos—ak—asr
                        "height": 540,
                        "width": 720,    
                        "images": [
                            {
                                "height": 1536,
                                "width": 2048,
                                "source": "https://fbcdn—sphotos-g—a.akamaihd.net/hphotos—
                            },
                            {
                                "height": 960,
```

As you see, there is a link after "picture" and "source". How can I get all of these links?

Thanks.

Comment: Why paste an image instead of plain text?

Comment: Had similar requirement last week, I used Json.Net framework. 
https://json.codeplex.com/releases
it's very easy to use and works well...

Comment: In addition to what @Ofir suggest, Json.NET can be queried with Linq as well, which might help you to get to the link values easier: http://james.newtonking.com/json/help/index.html

Comment: Thanks all and especial thanks for dear Quintium.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[How to: Serialize and Deserialize JSON Data](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb907644.aspx)

In .NET 4.0, there are [standard tools for working with JSON](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb907644.aspx). As an option - the [DataContractJsonSerializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.json.datacontractjsonserializer.aspx). Here is an example of its use. Describe data structures:

```
[DataContract]
public class ProfileType
{
    [DataMember]
    public int ProfileTypeIDT { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string SingularName { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string PluralName { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public ProfileField[] Fields { get; set; }
}

[DataContract]
public class ProfileField
{
    [DataMember]
    public int ProfileFieldIDT { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public int ProfileTypeIDT { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string FieldName { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string DataType { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public int Length { get; set; }
}

byte[] byteArray = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(jsonString);
MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(byteArray);
DataContractJsonSerializer serializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(ProfileType[]));
ProfileType[] profileTypes = (ProfileType[])serializer.ReadObject(stream);
```